# Jest: Mark function as untestable

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jestjs

I would like to reach 100% coverage on my javascript project using [Jest](http://facebook.github.io/jest/). Some methods, in my opinion, are not suited for unit testing and should be skipped when analyzing the code coverage. I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
function toto() {
    // Some function performing stuff we don't want to test e.g. 
    // promise called inside a complex authorization process 
    // involving an integration test really hard to mock.  
}

expect(toto()).toBeUntestable();
```

The [Jest API](http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/en/api.html) doesn't appear to have such possibility. It could be really useful since we could use this to aggregate bad code/hard-to-test code using this technique.

I'm really interested in your input regarding this situation since when it comes to tests, I find it really hard to have the right angle of approach.

Comment: Can we see some example of a code that is hard to test?

Comment: This is handled by Istanbul, so you can use `/* istanbul ignore next */` before the function

Comment: It sounds like you're saying two completely opposite things here: (1) I want 100% coverage, (2) I don't actually want 100% coverage. Which is it?

Comment: As it was mentioned, it's done with https://github.com/gotwarlost/istanbul/blob/master/ignoring-code-for-coverage.md . If the code is untestable  like *promise called inside a complex authorization process involving an integration test really hard to mock*, it requires refactoring, and this is exactly what coverage percentage is about.

Comment: @DuncanThacker The fact is: I don't really know what I want since I'm not familiar with unit testing. But based on this discussion, the best should be to do a code refactoring. Thanks for your input.